# Bad Sector on disk causes the whole server to crash

Tags: ssh, debian, server-crashes, dd

Our dedicated server's hard disk was recently diagnosed with bad-sectors, and each time certain data on the disk are about to get accessed, the whole server goes non-responding before i i issue a restart over robot panel.
We asked our server provider to install a new disk drive, and they did.
Now i want to hard-copy everything onto the new disk (as the old disk is also still attached), so i start the server in rescue mode (network boot) and run the following on the network-booted server via SSH (root):

```
ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sda /home/ddrescue.log
```

after about 5 minutes the server goes non-responding, and not even responding to SSH (as if the port is closed).

What could cause it? how can i prevent the server from going bananas when some faulty sectors are about to get accessed.

Comment: What file system do you use? Otherwise, maybe `man fsck` and use `fsck`?

Comment: The filesystem is EXT4

Comment: The symptoms you describe would not be caused by a bad sector. If the bad sector was on the disk the system was running from it could plausibly crash sshd. But with a bad sector on a disk you aren't actually running the system it would at most cause disk I/O to stall while it was trying to read the bad sector, but it wouldn't cause sshd to crash. And with sshd running from a rescue image in RAM it wouldn't even cause sshd to stall. If you accessed the disk using the `ext4` code in the kernel it can be configured to cause a panic on errors. But `ddrescue` wouldn't do that.

Comment: So why does the whole server freeze each time dd is past (in my case) 8,2 GB

Answer (score 1):

You should try enabling [TLER - time limited error recovery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control)

Without it, a disk with bad sectors will try reading the affected for 30+ second, possibly crashing the entire disk subsystem.

Comment: Apparently it's already enabled on the disk,
`smartctl -l scterc /dev/sdb` returns 70,70 (7 seconds for read and write)

Comment: Try to lower it (ie: 2 or 3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it your hardware/driver/whatever freezes when it encounters a bad block and you cannot proceed with the backup.

Do you have a list of bad blocks?

How about doing a logical backup (with tar, for example)?

The way I would approach this, but haven't tested:

- somehow get a list of bad blocks (`fsck.ext4` with `-c` and/or `-l`)?
- having the list of bad blocks, find files that are affected using `debugfs`:

> ```
>     icheck block ...
>           Print a listing of the inodes which use the one or  more  blocks
>           specified on the command line.
> ```

- create a logical backup with `tar --exclude`...

Good luck. :-s

Comment: I think the freeze occurs apparently everytime those bad-blocks are about to get accessed/read, so i think fsck.ext4 would also cause it to freeze when reaching those blocks, right?

Comment: Maybe. Do you get bad block information in ```dmesg```? Perhaps you could use that on the next run to skip them.

Comment: the whole server freezes completely, i won't be able to do anything run any command when it happens, unless i issue a hardware reset, and because its a network boot, all data is volatile and gone after reset

Comment: "Freezes completely" as in you lose network connection? Does it still ping? That's strange, but... do you have access to the kernel log in the admin panel?

Comment: now i ran fsck, gets this: "ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block"

Comment: yes i lose connection after freeze

Comment: Any chance the filesystem gets mounted with ```errors=panic```? Take a look at the ```sb=n``` mount option / ```-b``` ```fsck``` option.

Comment: the fstab looks normal without any errors=panic